# Как правильно сделать выгрузку через функцию?

Tags: php

Мне нужна прогрузка страницы через include.
Содержимое страницы вечно меняется - как и ее местоположение. Поэтому сделанно так что местоположение нужной страницы пишется в файле verif находящейся в каталоге Pattern

Сам код include:

```
$verif = getVR();
include $verif;
```

Код getVR:

```
function getVR() {
    $verif = "Pattern/verif";
    return json_decode(file_get_contents($verif), true);
    return $verif; 
}
```

Пример местоположения страницы:

```
form/form.php
```

Что сделано не так? Ибо точное местоположение файла указано правильно. А на выходе получаю белую страницу. Но если в include поставить самостоятельно положение то все работает.

Как сделать в рабочем состоянии?

Comment: Меня всегда удивляло, почему люди во-первых, изобретают какие-то адовы велосипеды, вместо того чтобы сделать нормально и просто, а во-вторых, до дрожи боятся объяснить - что им на самом деле надо, для какой цели этот бронированный велосипед на квадратных колесах им в принципе понадобился

Comment: @Ипатьев, наверное потому что созидание своими руками (или головой) тождественно открытию нового, лепки из глины, нежели чем использование имеющегося знания для составления домика из готовых кубиков. Мы же за этим и тянулись, когда шли в информатику, вы просто это забыли.

Comment: @DanielProtopopov особенно второй пункт, ага